# Alfresco Sharing Content Store

Tags: alfresco, conflict, alfresco-share, file-sharing

i'm using Alfresco 4.2.e version , the community edition one.
I have more instance of it and i want them to share the same meta db and the same file storing system. I know it's possible working on the configuration file.

My question is, if 2 or more alfresco instances share the same space on HD, how are handled the parallel access to the same resource? What about the conflicting access?

Is it already implemented? or should this policy be developed from the scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfresco can be divided in two areas, filesystem and DB holding metadata.

From the filesystem point of view I cannot imagine how an index could cope with two applications writing on it concurrently. Also, I don't think alfresco can lock filesystem element while accessing it.

From the database point of view, we are talking about two java web apps sharing the same db, which is absolutey evil. And there is lot of documentation about it.

If, on the other side, you mean same filesystem but different alf_data directory, and same db server but different DB, then nothing wrong could happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean clustering, then it is not available in community edition since 4.2.a version. You can read this post for more details: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/10/17/1745

Comment: not in clustering... i know it's for the enterprise edition. I mean: if i have 2 alfresco instances and i configure them to share the same file system, what will be happen if Instance1 and Instance2 want to access the same file? Should it rise a conflict exception, shouldn't?